# Getting individual bytes from hexadecimal value

Tags: java, hex, byte

Is there is a way I can get individual Bytes from a hexa decimal value in java

If I have a hexadecimal value 0x190(400), I want to get 0x90 and 0x01
If I have a hexadecimal value 0x89(137), I want to get 0x89 and 0x00

I am new to these and unable to find a way to get them individually.

Thank you for your help in advance

Thanks
R

Comment: thank you will try that and update you

Comment: Is this hexadecimal value represented as a String?

Comment: @jpact actually, I get an integer value lets say 400 which I want to get individual bytes of like 0x90 and 0x01

Comment: Got it. I posted the answer as one of possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your number is represented as the integral value, you can use bit mask to isolate particular byte.

```java
int value = 0x190;

byte byteValue = (byte) ((value >>> i*8) & 0xff);
String byteAsString = String.format("0x%02x", byteValue);
```

where `i` represents i-th byte (starting at 0)

Comment: public byte givememybyte(int position) {
        int value = 0x190;
        int mask = 0xff;

        byte byteValue = (byte) ((value >>> position*8) & mask);
        return byteValue;
    }
when i pass 0 then 1 as position, it returns -112 and 1, should be returning 0x90 and 0x01

Comment: Hi I wrote your code into a function and which is stated in the above comment

Comment: It returned proper values. Note that range of `byte` is <-128, 127>, that's why you see it as -112 (0x90 represented in base 10). Do you want to store that specific byte as String?

Comment: okay thank you let me try that in the proper code and will get back to you. thank you for being helpful

Comment: No worries! I've updated the answer and added String representation of extracted byte, as well.

Answer (score 0):

If is string value

like this:

```
let hexDecimal = "0x89(137)";
let splitValue = hexDecimal .split("(");
let response =  splitValue[0]; `
```